# Topshelf service crash

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, topshelf

I use Topshelf to host my WCF client (on Windows XP) that connects to WCF service (Windows Server 2008) and does some work on background.

When I was testing the service in the Console Application (in TopShelf) i didn't have any issues with that, but maybe because I restart the app from time to time.

Now I have deployed it as Windows Service, and it works good, but I have found several days ago that this service was not started, i checked the EventLog and found this:

"RemoteDeskService service ended unexpectedly for the third time." and no other information.

I use Topshelf 3.0.1 version and also use Log4Net for writing logs. It writes all logs properly, but nothing for this event, it seems like no one knows inside that something happened to the service.

I found in the TopShelf's code in WindowsHost that they have handler for AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException and it should write the log - but nothing is in the log.

Do you have any ideas where to look and what to do to resolve the issue?

I've checked my code - it is covered with try/catch blocks and I log exceptions, so I don't know what can cause this "unexpected end"

Thanks

Comment: If it's crashing the CLR, then there should be an event in the event log. Does it have anything? I'd also suggest getting on the mailing list, can likely get more help there. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topshelf-discuss

Comment: Make sure all of your WCF handlers are catching any exceptions, as an unhandled exception can take down the service pretty quickly and in a variety of ways that Topshelf may not be able to intercept.